# C# - Syntax Error in UPDATE Statement

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to update a database using C#, but I get the error: "Syntax error in UPDATE statement". I've looked around for other examples of this error, and found plenty, but every one is different. A lot of things can cause this error, and I just can't put my finger on this one.

```
query = String.Format(@"UPDATE PAYMENT 
                    SET MONTANT={0}, TYPE='4-Comptant',note='PPA',flag='O', date='{2:yyyyMMdd}'       
                    WHERE num_payment={1}", -payment, id, dt);
                    daUpdate.UpdateCommand.CommandText = query;
                    daUpdate.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  //update the table in the database
```

In debug mode, this is what the string ends up looking like:

```
UPDATE PAYMENT 
                                                SET MONTANT=-390, TYPE='4-Comptant',note='PPA',flag='O', date='20120601'
                                                WHERE num_payment=8
```

In the database, num_payment is a long integer and a primary key. MONTANT is a double, everything else is text.

Edit: Following people's advice, I've modified things a bit, but I'm still getting the same error. Here's what it looks like now:

```
                    OleDbCommand cmd = _con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE PAYMENT 
                    SET MONTANT=@montant, [TYPE]='4-Comptant',note='PPA',flag='O', [date]=@theDate 
                    WHERE num_payment=@numPayment";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montant", -payment);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dt));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numPayment", id);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The debug output looks the same
as before, except that now I see '@something' instead of the real value.

Comment: Try a different date format:  `date='{2:yyyy-MM-dd}'`

Comment: *database, num_payment is a long integer and a primary key. MONTANT is a double, everything else is text* Something's not what you think it is. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c71c6/1)

Comment: Use parameterized SQL (for multiple reasons).

Comment: @agent-j: I can't, the database is the way it is, I'm not allowed to change the formats. @

Comment: @agent-j: I'm not sure what you mean by strong, it shows up as "text" is MS Access. What I meant was that my boss gave me this database as it is, with entries already in this format. He doesn't want me changing the formats.

Comment: @ConradFrix: I'm not sure what you mean, I followed your link, and everything seems to be in order.

Comment: Please show table description (table create command).

Comment: @user1058303 that's my point *it worked fine*. This indicates that there's something different between the table and the description you gave.

Comment: @Ruben: I didn't use a query to create the table, so I can't show you a command I used to create it, but I could show you what it looks like in design view in MS Access: http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o530/totesmagotes83/screenshot_payment.png.

Comment: If you open your database in Access, and go to the window that allows you to create a new query, just paste in the value of the 'query' string. See if you can run it within Access, hopefully it will give you more information than just 'syntax error'. As it's not obvious what's wrong with this query, it might be that there's a trigger or constraint that might be being fired when the update is done, but I'd still expect it to return better error information. I've not used an access database for over 10 years, but I don't remember there being anything that different about it.

Comment: @RichS: I tried it using MS Access 2003, and the syntax error is the same in that as it is in C#.

Comment: Can you try removing parts of the expression until it works, i.e. remove each 'set' value one by one, then hopefully it will work as some point, and you'll know which one is causing the problem.. it's probably worth putting square brackets around all non-keywords, including [PAYMENT] (just in case).

Comment: OK, I found the problem. I had to have [] around 'note' and 'flag'.

Comment: @user1058303 - I suggested putting square brackets around all non-keywords in my previous comment. Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Put square brackets around [TYPE] and [DATE] these are SQL keywords.

```
query = String.Format(@"UPDATE PAYMENT  
                SET MONTANT={0}, [TYPE]='4-Comptant',note='PPA',flag='O', [date]='{2:yyyyMMdd}'        
                WHERE num_payment={1}", -payment, id, dt); 
                daUpdate.UpdateCommand.CommandText = query; 
                daUpdate.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  //update the table in the
```

Comment: The question is tagged `mysql`, and MySQL doesn't use `[]` as name delimiters. `TYPE` and `DATE` are [*not* reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html "Reserved Words (MySQL)") (`DATE` is a keyword, but not a reserved word).

Comment: Actually, that's my mistake, its just plain SQL. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

The fields 'note' and 'flag' needed to have [] around them. I added these and now the query doesn't give that error anymore.